# IMACROS .JS on FF - How to delete first row of source csv file in the end of macro?

Tags: javascript, csv, imacros

I have a script in .js for imacros, it works well but i need code that script will delete first row/line of source data csv file when macro play is finished. So first row will be replaced by second row in second run of macro and macro will use first row always

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you want something that would delete first row and move the text to the top?

For that you have to use JavaScript scripting. The process would go like this:

1. Load file
2. Delete first row
3. Delete the file
4. Save the text to that file (newly created)

It might look complicated but it's not that hard. Good luck in coding. Useful links.

http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference

http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL

http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS